# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Orchestration Step Precondition Actions

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to have a precondition action which specifies that an orchestration step should be performed rather than skipped?

Working with custom policies I have seen many cases where the precondition action specifies *SkipThisOrchestrationStep*

Instead of this:

```
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>extension_hasUpdatedPwd</Value>
          <Value>True</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
       <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>extension_isMigrated</Value>
          <Value>False</Value>
          <Action>ExecuteThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
```

My use case is that I have a custom attribute which specifies if a password has been reset. If a user has that attribute set to "false", then I want to perform the orchestration step. If a user has that attribute set to true or that attribute does not exist, then I want to skip that orchestration step.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/42548998-add-additional-conditions-to-b2c-logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a list of preconditions such as this:

```xml
<Preconditions>
  <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
    <Value>extension_isMigrated</Value>
    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
  </Precondition>
  <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
    <Value>extension_isMigrated</Value>
    <Value>False</Value>
    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
  </Precondition>
</Preconditions>
```

Currently, `Action` can only be set to `SkipThisOrchestrationStep`. So if you don't want to skip the current step, then `ExecuteActionsIf` must be set to `false`.

Comment: ugh, feature request.  I was just asked for a business justification by the B2C team as to why i need my IEF upload limit increased ... well because it takes me 15KB just to write a simple conditional statement after I capture, null check, copyclaims ...

Comment: Why do we have to check for ClaimsExist and then check for ClaimEquals for Boolean ?