# AAD B2C Validation technical profile with multiple preconditions in logical AND

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've recently started working on Azure Active Directory B2C custom policies. I'm trying to understand how to add multiple preconditions to a validation technical profile so that it is skipped if all of the conditions are true (logical AND). The default behaviour is OR.
This is part of my custom policy definition in a DisplayControl > Actions block.

```xml
<Action Id="VerifyCode">
    <ValidationClaimsExchange>
        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp">
            <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>email</Value>
                    <Value>automatedtest@test.com</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>otp</Value>
                    <Value>7777777</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>
            </Preconditions>
        </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
    </ValidationClaimsExchange>
</Action>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is skipping this validation technical profile if the email claim is automatedtest@test.com and the otp claim is 7777777.
I've been looking into [string claim transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations) that I could use to concatenate the two string claims to obtain a single string and then compare that to the test value, but that sounds really dumb.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the answer. Would be useful to see some docs on this.

Anyway, the really long-winded way to do this is:

Have a TP with three claims transformations. Call the TP as a step in the journey.

The first does a CompareClaims against the email

The second does a CompareClaims against the OTP

The third does a boolean AndClaims against the above two booleans

Use the output as a precondition.

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar in the end. I created a claims transformation that concatenates the 2 claims and then compares the output with the test value in a precondition of the validation technical profile. Life would be much easier if you could just concatenate multiple preconditions in one place.

Comment: Hope you have referred this documentation link of Azure AD B2C AND claims transformations for the above precondition also: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#andclaims

Answer (score -3):

•   Precondition is an orchestrationstep element that must be followed through for a successful transaction. If any step fails, the transaction fails. Also, Azure AD B2C evaluates the preconditions in list order. The order-based preconditions allow you to set the order in which the preconditions are applied since these are a part of the user journey.

**The first precondition that satisfied overrides all the subsequent preconditions. The orchestration step is executed only if all the preconditions are not satisfied.**

Thus, the basic structure of the precondition element itself is based on an ‘OR’ condition and both claims, i.e., email and OTP can’t be passed in the same precondition element, due to which your requirement of the conditions to be logically ‘AND’ cannot be configured.

Also, other than ‘SkipThisOrchestrationStep’, no other action can be passed in the precondition element due to which redirecting to another precondition through it also cannot be done.

•   But you can configure your precondition likewise below to go through both the precondition and then skip the orchestration step: -

```
           <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>email</Value>
                <Value>automatedtest@test.com</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>automatedtest@test.com</Value>
    <Value>true</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>otp</Value>
                <Value>7777777</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
            </Precondition>
           </Preconditions>
```

Though, it becomes somewhat lengthy but satisfies your requirement of checking both the claims. Please find the below community thread for more details into this: -

[Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Orchestration Step Precondition Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226867/azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-orchestration-step-precondition-actions)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#precondition

Comment: If you look at the link you posted, there is a "ClaimsExist" and a "ClaimsEquals". Your example is missing the "ClaimsExist"?

Comment: Yes, my example is missing the 'ClaimsExist' because in this precondition, the value has to be matched initially with the specified claim and if the value doesn't match, this precondition will not be executed and at skipped at large and if incase it matched then will be proceeded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT. I'm struggling to understand precondition 2 in your example. It compares 2 static values: 'automatedtest@test.com' and 'true' (instead of a claim).

Comment: The second precondition does compare the 'automatedtest@test.com' and 'true' value but not as a claim but as a returned value from the precondition above it. Due to which, every time, the email is detected, both the claims are checked.

Comment: This isn't working for me sadly. I just copied your example on my policy @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT. The validation technical profile isn't skipped when it should. Also, it's not perfectly clear to me how the value from the 1st condition ends up on the second and how comparing 2 different static values can ever result in a match (in the 2nd condition). It would be great if there was some documentation around this on Microsoft docs. Thanks for your help.